# How can I delete lines that older than 7 days by date column?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have csv file like this:

```
DATE,DATA1,DATA2
16.05.2015,/home/spy,grid.csv
16.05.2015,/home/ora,grid2.csv
16.05.2015,/home/ted,grid3.csv
05.05.2015,/home/old,iamold.delete.me
```

I need to check DATE values and if it's older than 7 days, delete this line.

I try like this(with seconds)

```
while read -r line;
do
line2=${line}

now=$(date +"%s")

lines=$(awk -F, '{print $1}' $line2) 

linedate=$(date --date="$lines" +"%s")

(( diff = (now - linedate) / 86400 ))

done < "csvfile.csv"
```

How can I do it easier? And how can I delete line directly, without mv/tmp solutions?

Comment: `how can I delete line directly, without mv/tmp solutions` - why do you care? Any solution will use a tmp file, whether you provide the name for it or not, so what difference does it make?

Comment: `awk` can be avoided here but remaining will probably be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ awk -F'[,.]' 'NR==1 || (systime()-mktime($3" "$2" "$1" 0 0 0")) <= 7*24*60*60' file
DATE,DATA1,DATA2
16.05.2015,/home/spy,grid.csv
16.05.2015,/home/ora,grid2.csv
16.05.2015,/home/ted,grid3.csv
```

Use `-i inplace` if it matters to you to save a few characters or just use `> tmp && mv tmp file` like for any command.